# on clicking a item in JList of java,how do I open new window or new frame?

Tags: java

```
 private void channelItemsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(channelItems.getSelectedIndex()>=0)
    {

        JPanel p1=new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter your username below", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        p1.add(label);
        add(p1);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. For you its to note: "must describe the specific problem". Just to elt you know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen double click of `MouseListener`, otherwise it will open dialog with every mouse click.

```
ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel..
JList list=new JList(listSelectionModel);


list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
          //...Show the JDialog or JOptionPane here, not JPanel.
         String name=JOptoinPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your username");
    }
  }
});
```

For details, go through this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Comment: This will open a dialog each time you change the selection, be it by mouse, keyboard or programatically

Comment: Thank you,but after clicking the list item,I need to have even text area and all which would be a new frame

Comment: @user3016481, Than use JDialog.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, You're right, `MouseListener` with double click is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

simply make :

```
actionMethod(...){
    currentPanel.dispose();
    newPanel.setVisible(true);
}
```